# Not fully connected layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I want to create a network where in the input layer nodes are just connected to some nodes in the next layer. Here is a small example:

[image]

My solution so far is that I set the weight of the edge between `i1` and `h1` to zero and after every optimization step I multiply the weights with a matrix (I call this matrix mask matrix) in which every entry is 1 except the entry of the weight of the edge between `i1` and `h1`.
(See code below)

Is this approach right? Or does this have a affect on the GradientDescent? Is there another approach to create this kind of a network in TensorFlow?

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.contrib.eager as tfe
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()


model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid, input_shape=(2,)),  # input shape required
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=tf.sigmoid)
])


#set the weights
weights=[np.array([[0, 0.25],[0.2,0.3]]),np.array([0.35,0.35]),np.array([[0.4,0.5],[0.45, 0.55]]),np.array([0.6,0.6])]

model.set_weights(weights)

model.get_weights()

features = tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.05,0.10 ]])
labels =  tf.convert_to_tensor([[0.01,0.99 ]])


mask =np.array([[0, 1],[1,1]])

#define the loss function
def loss(model, x, y):
  y_ = model(x)
  return tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, predictions=y_)

#define the gradient calculation
def grad(model, inputs, targets):
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    loss_value = loss(model, inputs, targets)
  return loss_value, tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_variables) 

#create optimizer an global Step
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)
global_step = tf.train.get_or_create_global_step()


#optimization step
loss_value, grads = grad(model, features, labels)
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.variables),global_step)

#masking the optimized weights 
weights=(model.get_weights())[0]
masked_weights=tf.multiply(weights,mask)
model.set_weights([masked_weights])
```

Comment: Is it just a toy example or are you looking for a solution for this specific example?

Answer (score 12):

If you are looking for a solution for the specific example you provided, you can simply use `tf.keras` Functional API and define two Dense layers where one is connected to both neurons in the previous layer and the other one is only connected to one of the neurons:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layer import Input, Lambda, Dense, concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

inp = Input(shape=(2,))
inp2 = Lambda(lambda x: x[:,1:2])(inp)   # get the second neuron 

h1_out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inp2)  # only connected to the second neuron
h2_out = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(inp)  # connected to both neurons
h_out = concatenate([h1_out, h2_out])

out = Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(h_out)

model = Model(inp, out)

# simply train it using `fit`
model.fit(...)
```

Comment: is it possible to pass an array of indexes, instead of the slice `[:,1:2]`? Something like `[:,[1,2,5]]`

Comment: @L.B. As far as I know, unlike Numpy, that's not possible since the indices should be either slices or scalars. However, instead you can use [`tf.gather`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) for this purpose like: `tf.gather(x, [1,2,5], axis=1)`, this gives you the equivalent of `x[:, [1,2,5]]`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your solution and some others suggested by other answers in this post is that they do not **prevent** training of this weight. They allow the gradient descent to train the non existent weight and then overwrite it retrospectively. This will result in a network that has a zero in this location as desired, but will negatively affect your training process as the back propagation calculation will not see the masking step as it is not part of a TensorFlow graph and so the gradient descent will follow a path which includes the assumption that this weight **does** have an affect on the outcome (it does not).

A better solution would be to include the masking step as a part of your TensorFlow graph, so that it can be factored into the gradient descent. Since the masking step is simply a element wise multiplication by your sparse, binary martix `mask`, you could just include the `mask` matrix as an elementwise matrix multiplicaiton in the graph definition using `tf.multiply`.

Sadly this means sying goodbye to the user friendly keras,layers methods and embracing a more nuts & bolts approach to TensorFlow. I can't see an obvious way to do it using the layers API.

See the implementation below, I have tried to provide comments explaining what is happening at each stage.

```
import tensorflow as tf

## Graph definition for model

# set up tf.placeholders for inputs x, and outputs y_
# these remain fixed during training and can have values fed to them during the session
with tf.name_scope("Placeholders"):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name="x")   # input layer
    y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2], name="y_") # output layer

# set up tf.Variables for the weights at each layer from l1 to l3, and setup feeding of initial values
# also set up mask as a variable and set it to be un-trianable
with tf.name_scope("Variables"):
    w_l1_values = [[0, 0.25],[0.2,0.3]]
    w_l1 = tf.Variable(w_l1_values, name="w_l1")
    w_l2_values = [[0.4,0.5],[0.45, 0.55]]
    w_l2 = tf.Variable(w_l2_values, name="w_l2")

    mask_values = [[0., 1.], [1., 1.]]
    mask = tf.Variable(mask_values, trainable=False, name="mask")


# link each set of weights as matrix multiplications in the graph. Inlcude an elementwise multiplication by mask.
# Sequence takes us from inputs x to output final_out, which will be compared to labels fed to placeholder y_
l1_out = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, tf.multiply(w_l1, mask)), name="l1_out")
final_out = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l1_out, w_l2), name="output")


## define loss function and training operation
with tf.name_scope("Loss"):
    # some loss defined as a function of graph output: final_out and labels: y_
    loss = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_out, labels=y_, name="loss")

with tf.name_scope("Train"):
    # some optimisation strategy, arbitrary learning rate
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, name="optimizer_adam")
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, name="train_op")


# create session, initialise variables and train according to inputs and corresponding labels
# This should show that the values of the first layer weights change, but the one set to 0 remains at 0
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    initial_l1_weights = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("Variables/w_l1:0")
    print(initial_l1_weights.eval())

    inputs = [[0.05, 0.10]]
    labels = [[0.01, 0.99]]
    ans = sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={"Placeholders/x:0": inputs, "Placeholders/y_:0": labels})

    train_steps = 1
    for i in range(train_steps):
        initial_l1_weights = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name("Variables/w_l1:0")
    print(initial_l1_weights.eval())
```

Or use the answer provided by *today* for a keras friendly option.

Comment: FYI, my answer does not include that extra weight you mention as it has two separate Dense layers.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "will negatively affect your training process"? Does it mean that the optimization will not work probably or does it mean that the training process is just slower?  As my original problem is a lot more complex (9180 Input nodes) I would really like to keep working with keras.

Comment: I means that you are optimising your network based on a cost function that is *not* the cost function by which you assess its success/failure. 

You train the network by optimizing it as if this weight *was* there, and then take it out. This is bound to produce an inferior result compared to optimizing for the weight not being there.

Comment: Imagine you have a sum: *a* + *b* + *c* = 100 and you want to optimize this. You do so and get *a*=33.3, *b* = 33.3, *c*=33.4. Perfect. But then set *a*=0 and you have a sub optimal solution. Repeatedly doing this may slowly progress towards an optimal solution, but it will never get there, and in a non-convex problem such as yours may leave you stuck in a poor local minimum.

Comment: Having re-read it, it seems that the answer provided by _today_ does not cause this problem. So go with that. (I will amend my answer accordingly).

Comment: **better example:** Imagine optimizing: **ab** + **c** = 100, **a** + **b** = 51. If you do this to get **a** =50, **b** =1, **c** =50, an optimal solution is found. But then set **a** =0 and you now have a poor solution. Differentiating with respect to **a** will now give the greatest gradient since its value affects both equations, so continuing optimisation will likely push **a** back towards 50. This cycle can repeat, without finding a good solution where **a** =0.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options here.

First, you could use the dynamic masking approach in your example. I believe this will work as expected since the gradients w.r.t. the masked-out parameters will be zero (the output is constant when you change the unused parameters). This approach is simple and it can be used even when your mask is not constant during the training.

Second, if you know beforehand which weights will be always zero, you can compose your weight matrix using `tf.get_variable` to get a submatrix, and then concatenate it with a `tf.constant` tensor, e.g.:

```
weights_sub = tf.get_variable("w", [dim_in, dim_out - 1])
zeros = tf.zeros([dim_in, 1])
weights = tf.concat([weights_sub, zeros], axis=1)
```

this example will make one column of your weight matrix to be always zero.

Finally, if your mask is more complex, you can use `tf.get_variable` on a flattened vector and then compose a `tf.SparseTensor` with the variable values on the used indices:

```
weights_used = tf.get_variable("w", [num_used_vars])
indices = ...  # get your indices in a 2-D matrix of shape [num_used_vars, 2]
dense_shape = tf.constant([dim_in, dim_out])  # this is the final shape of the weight matrix
weights = tf.SparseTensor(indices, weights_used, dense_shape)
```

EDIT: This probably won't work in combination with Keras' `set_weights` method, as it expects Numpy arrays, not Tensors.