# effect of masking layer

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a neural network model where the input data has many missing values which are hard to fill in by any means in advance. Therefore, the idea is to train a neural network with only observed data. The data vector fed in the input layer is then a vector with missing values in various positions. The positions of the missing values will not be fixed.

After some search, I found Tensorflow has a masking layer for use. Therefore, I inserted a masking layer right after the input layer,

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(inputDim,))
maskingLayer = keras.Masking(mask_value = -999)(inputs)
```

where the missing values are replaced with -999 in the preprocessing. After that, several dense layers are inserted and the model was compiled and fit in usual way.

The question is that I don't see much effect of the masking layer. I am wondering if the masking layer really masked out all the nodes of value -999 in the input layer as well as the weights and biases connected to them?

I found this post who had a similar question 
[Not fully connected layer in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851652/not-fully-connected-layer-in-tensorflow)
However, his unwanted links are fixed and in my case I would like to build a layer (next to the input layer) that only connects to the unmasked nodes of the input layer. Is it possible to do it? 
Thanks.